# Python declare numpy array 'tuple' is not callable (in jupyter notebook?)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Source:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[11,12,13],[21,22,23]])

print(a)
```

Error on line 1:

> TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

[image]

I do not understand what is going on here, since I wrote `import numpy as np`.

Comment: Please [do not post screenshots of code or errors messages](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) - post as text a [mcve]here so others facing the same problem are able to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to restart the Kernel through 'Kernel' -> 'Restart' because you might have saved 'a' into a variable 'print' like this before:

```
print = a
```

So now print is not the built-in print function anymore but a tuple